# Koding - Yeoman - AngularFullStack Cannot Create Scaffolding

Tags: node.js, yeoman, angular-fullstack, koding

Hello i am using Koding Cloud Based Ubuntu Development environment.

I've managed to is install all prerequisites required for Yeoman Angular FullStack.

Installed Successfully below items

1. sudo npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower karma
2. sudo npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack

After installing above.

i've created abltd directory (Folder structure shown below)

and ran following command

yo angular-fullstack abltd

it ran all to the end and throwing following error.

1070 error Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/abitandco/tmp/npm-1293-IkfHqNho'
1070 error  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/abitandco/tmp/npm-1293-IkfHqNho']
1070 error   errno: 3,
1070 error   code: 'EACCES',
1070 error   path: '/home/abitandco/tmp/npm-1293-IkfHqNho',
1070 error   parent: 'abltd' }
1071 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
1072 error System Linux 3.13.0-29-generic
1073 error command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
1074 error cwd /home/abitandco/abltd
1075 error node -v v0.10.26
1076 error npm -v 1.4.3
1077 error path /home/abitandco/tmp/npm-1293-IkfHqNho
1078 error code EACCES
1079 error errno 3
1080 error stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/abitandco/tmp/npm-1293-IkfHqNho'
1081 verbose exit [ 3, true ]

i tried running as sudo yo angular-fullstack abltd but no difference.

i am adding complete log and image as well to help understand problem better.

Can anyone point me in right direction please.

[image]

I have complete npm debug log if any one wants to see it.

Comment: Remember one thing, you should never use ```sudo``` with ```npm```. It might be the issue in your case. Might be some folder which is used to scaffold the app is owned by the root.

Answer (score 0):

its likely that your `~/.npm` or `~/tmp` directories are owned by the root user. try again but ensure that those directories are owned by your username.

Comment: Thanks Nitin i did exactly that and is all sorted

Answer (score 0):

Give yourself permission using the following command

```
sudo chown -R youruser /home/youruser
```